# Wordpress on Azure URL settings with custom domain name

Tags: wordpress, azure, dns

I purchased a custom domain from Google domains.  (jewelrystoreforsale.com)
I set up a WordPress web app in Azure.  (js4s.azurewebsites.net)

I changed the DNS settings in Google domains to:
[image]

I changed the custom domains in Azure to:
[image]

I then went and installed a free theme.  That's all I've done.

When I browse to the site, the home page shows the custom domain, but all the links, link to js4s.azurewebsites.net.  I tried to change the URL in the settings, but of course that crashed everything.  I changed it back by accessing the database directly and updating the wp_options table.

How can I make the urls and links point to my custom domain?

Answer (score -3):

It turns out that you can't change the URL settings via the admin control panel.  I followed the instructions from here: http://divineops.net/custom-domain-in-wordpress-on-azure-web-app/ and it worked.

Here is the specific section that helped me understand the problem.

---

**DO NOT** update it through WordPress Dashboard => Settings => General. This does not work (at least currently) and might lock you out of the application! 
Instead you will need to FTP into your site and change the functions.php of your currently active theme.

---

Comment: Link is dead :(